# Why am I getting the 'numpy.int64' object is not callable'?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to make a program that will go through a Excel file that contains meteorological data and make several smaller files with a subset of this larger file.
The next dataframe (p1) is a example of the file I'm trying to separate, the only differences is that I have more occurrences of rows with the same number of 'EstacaoCodigo'. The other data frame has a list with a relation between a station code and where it is located.

```
p1 = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'EstacaoCodigo': [4, 5, 1647006, 8], 'col_2': ['A', 'bb', 'C', 'e']}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(p1)


ploca = {'Codigo': [3, 1647006, 1, 0], 'EstadoCodigo': ['26', '26', '26', '27']}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ploca)
```

This is the code that I have for it

```
p1 = pd.read_excel("Chuvas_ba_go_df_ate_7302064.xlsx")
ploca = pd.read_excel("Estacao_df_go.xlsx",usecols=['EstadoCodigo','Codigo'])

est = p1.loc[0,'EstacaoCodigo']
ind = 1
foi = pd.Series([])
print(est)
while est not in foi:
  ptemp=p1[p1['EstacaoCodigo']==est].reset_index(drop=True)
  estado = ploca['EstadoCodigo'].map(est)
  if estado == 26:
    estado = 'GO'
  elif estado == 27:
    estado = 'DF'
  ptemp.to_excel('estacao_',estado,'_',est,'.xlsx')
  foi.append(est)
  ind += ptemp['EstacaoCodigo'].iget(-1)
  est = p1.loc[ind,'EstacaoCodigo']
```

However when I run it I get this message, I tried searching what this (TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable) means, however I couldn't understand what the error is. Thanks in advance  and sorry if there is something wrong with the question

```
1647006

<ipython-input-2-1a4a61eaa286>:3: FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  foi = pd.Series([])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-2-1a4a61eaa286> in <cell line: 5>()
      5 while est not in foi:
      6   ptemp=p1[p1['EstacaoCodigo']==est].reset_index(drop=True)
----> 7   estado = ploca['EstadoCodigo'].map(est)
      8   if estado == 26:
      9     estado = 'GO'

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in map(self, arg, na_action)
   4537         dtype: object
   4538         """
-> 4539         new_values = self._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
   4540         return self._constructor(new_values, index=self.index).__finalize__(
   4541             self, method="map"

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/base.py in _map_values(self, mapper, na_action)
    888 
    889         # mapper is a function
--> 890         new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
    891 
    892         return new_values

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable
```

Comment: `ploca['EstadoCodigo'].map(est)` doesn't make sense. What were you trying to do there?

Comment: The purpose of `map()` is to specify a function that will be applied to each element in a dataframe.  But you did not pass a function.  Why not?

Comment: I was trying to get the location code from the location dataframe using the station code. Getting the value from the first column in the row that has the specific station code (est) .

Comment: But why are you using `map()` to do that?

Comment: I tried using the .loc parameter but couldn't make it work.